# Trying to get program to quit when "quit" is typed. C++

Tags: c++, exit

I'm currently trying to get my program to quit when "quit" is typed out but it won't work and nothing happens. On occasion it terminates it. I'm super new to all coding so any help is appreciated. This is what I have written for it:

Below is what the readline references in the code's first part. I received help writing all of this and now without that help by my side, it's challenging for me to understand. Learning moment I guess.

```
int main(){
    int length = 1024;
    char *mainInput = new char[length];
    Start(mainInput, length - 1);
    delete []mainInput;
    return 0;
}

void Start(char* &input, int length){
    char message[] = "Type quit to exit program. Type any other line to begin: ";
    ReadLine(input, length, message);
    if(strstr(input, "quit")){
        cout << "Terminating program." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Youre string is: " << input << endl;
    int option;
    cout << "Choose option: (Vowels_Vs_Consonants (1), Letter_Swap (2), Flip_String (3), Palindrone_Detector(4), Words_Frequency(5)): ";
    cin >> option;
    switch(option){
        case 1:
            vowels_vs_consonants(input);
            break;
        case 2:
            letter_swap(input);
            cout << "Our new string: " << input << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            reverse_string(input);
            cout << "Original: " << input << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            if(is_palindrome(input)){
                cout << "It is a palindrome." << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "It is not a palindrome." << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            word_frequency(input);
            break;
        default:
            Start(input, length);
            break;
    }
    cin.clear();
    Start(input, length);
}



Added code for understanding:

void ReadLine(char* &charArray, int length, char* message){
    cin.clear();
    cout << message; cin.getline(charArray, length);
    if(cin.fail()){
        cin.ignore(length,'\n');
        cin.clear();
        ReadLine(charArray, length, message);
    }
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}


I've tried messing around with the capitalization factor but I can't get it to compile.
```

Comment: On the one hand, line numbers make it easier to say things like "On line 31 you call a function `ReadLine`. Where is that function defined?" But it also makes it way harder to copy and paste this code and try to run it ourselves.

Comment: I suspect you are using something in `Readline` that reads and includes the trialing `'\n'` in `input` so when you `strcmp()` `"quit\n"` doesn't match `"quit"`. Further, use `std::string` instead of allocating with `new` with a `char*` type for new programs. There is no reason to mix C  and C++ to compare strings. Pick a language and use one, not both. (there are some areas where C provides functions that C++ doesn't -- but string comparison isn't one of those areas)

Comment: @kaiblu The formatting is improved, but my follow-up question of "what's actually happening inside `ReadLine`?" remains

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There is no use of `strcmp` here, only `strstr`. `strstr("quit\n", "quit")` should be true-ish.

Comment: Chuckling -- my eyes really are getting as old as I am ... Thank you @NathanPierson for helping me feel young again -- not `:)`

Comment: I have added additional code! let me know if that helps understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

void ReadLine(char*& input, int length, char* message) {
    std::cout << message;
    //std::cin >> input; // this line does not work if you want the cstring to have space. Example :"asd 123" would only return "asd"
    std::cin.getline(input, length);
    //std::cin.getline(input, length, '\n');
}

// I did not change anything below, so I assume the problem is in your ReadLine()
void Start(char*& input, int length) {
    char message[] = "Type quit to exit program. Type any other line to begin: ";
    ReadLine(input, length, message);
    if (strstr(input, "quit")) {
        std::cout << "Terminating program." << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    std::cout << "Youre string is: " << input << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    Start(input, length);
}

int main() {
    int length = 1024;
    char* mainInput = new char[length];
    Start(mainInput, length - 1);
    delete[]mainInput;
    return 0;
}
```

I think what is wrong is within your ReadLine() function. As I do not know what your ReadLine() contains, I am assuming what other commentators are saying is the case (you are reading the newline character as well). The above solution works but I do not know if it is the problem you are having.

Another solutions I can think of are:

1. trimming the "input" variable to get rid of the newline character at the end before the "strstr".
2. Adding a cin.ignore('\n'); somewhere

(Note: I copied your code and deleted some of it to make my solution more readable. I am a student so my code might not be the most reasonable/optimized too)

Hope it helps!